# maximum number of bridges ? How to keep system performant with high numbers?

Tags: networking, network-bridge, router

We do run a Linux as Router between several IP networks. some of them are at Linux bridges to handle several vlans on on ip if. ebtables is in place to do the port isolation.
Currently 297 Bridges are created and the system isnt anymore that spontaneously during creation of new ones or bringing down/up them.
The System is a 24cores 32G Ram server with 3 physical interfaces.

May be someone knows which performance screws are important to keep the bridge-utils as quick as at the beginning.

during bringup the /lib/udev/bridge-network-interfaces seems to be on high load

Comment: Is this related to https://support.cumulusnetworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/216420547-Calculating-the-Limitation-of-a-Linux-Bridge-In-Traditional-Mode ? That claims a soft limit of 200 before you start seeing a performance hit.

Comment: may be..... I'm not using all these cumulus things and also not using vxlan but on the other hand.. its sounds pointing into the same direction